# Sharing a variable in Android application

Tags: android

I have a json file. So, I was parsed the json file and I want to share `jsonarray.length()` value all the classes in application. So, what is recommended way to do that??

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1:** you can set it public static

**Option 2:** you can store it in a SharePreference

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Application class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and store the info you need in a field;
anyway I think the best solutions have already been suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

First one is to store it in a private static variable and expose a method to share it with others.

Second one is to expose it as a public static variable

Third one is to store in [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. Figure out a way to eliminate the need to store it, by passing it as an argument.
2. Store it in SharedPreferences.